# Two-part model in R caret

Tags: r-caret

### Problem

I am using the 'caret' package to train and test prediction models. I have left-skewed data that ranges from -0.138 to 0.9489, with more observations around 0.9489. I would like to run a two-part model comprised of logistic regression (observations with 0.9489=1 and and all other values=0) and OLS. **Is there a model within the caret package that conducts two-part models or would I have to build this on my own within caret?**

### What I've tried

a) I've looked through the available models in caret and can't find one specifically for two-part models. Should I run the logistic and linear regression separately and somehow combine them within caret?

b) I've attempted to build the model, but am struggling to fill in the model components (see below).

### Code

```
##Logistic and OLS models
logistic <- glm(binary_outcome ~ lung_function + age + male + pkyrs + disease_type , 
                 data = data, 
                 family = 'binomial')
ols <- lm(outcome ~ lung_function + age + male + pkyrs + disease_type , 
      data = data)

##Cross-validation using caret package
set.seed(123) 
train.control <- trainControl(
method = "cv", 
number = 10)

##Novice attempt at creating two-part model (get stuck at parameters)
model_list <- list(type="Regression", 
         library=NULL)

parameters <- data.frame(parameter = c(""))
```

Comment: https://data.library.virginia.edu/getting-started-with-hurdle-models/ might be helfpul

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My understanding is that hurdle models are for zero-inflated data (mine has the opposite skewness) and I would have to inverse my data. Looks like I may end up doing the cross-validation manually.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to just more or less do it manually.
I am currently trying to do this with a negative binomial hurdle model (outline of code below). I have tested and compared it (with basic linear models) to output from caret and values are very similar. I would be interested to know if anyone thinks this is a terrible idea.

```
#I think you can use this to get your fitted values, which I store in the main data frame so they can be easily compared to the expected values. 
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  train_set<-df[-i,]
  model1<-(**ENTER MODEL HERE AND MAKE "data=train_set"**)
  df[i,"fitted_value"] <- predict(model1, newdata = df[i,])}

#Then, you can do whatever types of comparisons you want...
#Visually compare fitted to expected
plot(df$Expected, df$fitted_value)

RMSE<-sqrt(mean((df$fitted_value-df$Expected)^2));RMSE#Root mean squared error

MAE<-(1/(nrow(df)))*sum(abs(df$fitted_value-df$Expected));MAE#Mean Absolute Error
```

Comment: I see now that you are using `method = CV` not `method = LOOCV`. Perhaps, the same code could be adapted for CV instead of LOOCV